# How can I get a total from two functions?

Tags: c++, function, loops

I'm working on a project and have written code that determines how much money is spent in one day - the only problem is that I need to make it so the day 1 totals are outputted, then day 2 starts (with just the day 2 totals outputted), and then day 3 starts (with just the day 2 totals outputted) and then after all 3 days have ended, a total of totals from the 3 days is outputted. I'll paste my code in, but for some reason the formatting is messed up. Thank you!

```
void drillDay ()
{
    int dayCounter = 1;
    while (dayCounter > 0)
    {
        //Enlisted Soldiers, total number of Soldiers who attend
        int privatesRankOneTotal = 0;
        int privatesRankTwoTotal = 0;
        int privatesRankThreeTotal = 0;
        int specialistsCorporalsTotal = 0;
        int sergeantsTotal = 0;
        int staffSergeantsTotal = 0;
        int pltSergeantsTotal = 0;
        int masterSergeantsTotal = 0;

    //Warrant Officers, total number of Warrant Officers who attend
    int chiefWarrantRankOneTotal = 0;
    int chiefWarrantRankTwoTotal = 0;
    int chiefWarrantRankThreeTotal = 0;

    //Officers, total number of officers who attend
    int ltRankTwoTotal = 0;
    int ltRankOneTotal = 0;
    int captainsTotal = 0;

    //How much each soldier is paid per day, based on rank.
    double pvtOnePay = 99.40;
    double pvtTwoPay = 111.42;
    double pfcPay = 117.16;
    double SpcCplPay = 136.42;
    double sgtPay = 165.84;
    double ssgPay = 229.12;
    double sfcPay = 239.32;
    double msgPay = 309.44;

    double cwoOnePay = 233.40;
    double cwoTwoPay = 274.92;
    double cwoThreePay = 336.04;

    double ltTwoPay = 188.56;
    double ltOnePay = 294.96;
    double cptPay = 335.40;

    cout<<endl<<"Enter amount of enlisted soldiers:"<<endl<<endl;

    cout<<"How many Privates (E-1) / (PVT) are attending drill today?  "<<endl;
    cin>>privatesRankOneTotal;
    cout<<"How many Privates (E-2) / (PV2) are attending drill today?  "<<endl;
    cin>>privatesRankTwoTotal;
    cout<<"How many Privates (E-3) / (PFC) are attending drill today?  "<<endl;
    cin>>privatesRankThreeTotal;
    cout<<"How many Specialists / Corporals (E-4) / (SPC / CPL) are attending drill today? ";
    cin>>specialistsCorporalsTotal;
    cout<<"How many Sergeants (E-5) / (SGT) are attending drill today?  "<<endl;
    cin>>sergeantsTotal;
    cout<<"How many Staff Sergeants (E-6) / (SSG) are attending drill today?  "<<endl;
    cin>>staffSergeantsTotal;
    cout<<"How many Platoon Sergeants (E-7) / (SFC) are attending drill today?  "<<endl;
    cin>>pltSergeantsTotal;
    cout<<"How many soldiers with the paygrade of (E-8) are attending drill today?  "<<endl;
    cin>>masterSergeantsTotal;

    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;

    cout<<"Enter amount of Warrant Officers:"<<endl<<endl;

    cout<<"How many Warrant Officers (W-1) / (WO1) are attending drill today?  "<<endl;
    cin>>chiefWarrantRankOneTotal;
    cout<<"How many Warrant Officers  (W-2) / (CW2) are attending drill today?  "<<endl;
    cin>>chiefWarrantRankTwoTotal;
    cout<<"How many Warrant Officers (W-3) / (CW3) are attending drill today?  "<<endl;
    cin>>chiefWarrantRankThreeTotal;

    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;

    cout<<"Enter amount of Officers:"<<endl<<endl;

    cout<<"How many 2nd Lieutenants (O-1) / (2LT) are attending drill today?  "<<endl;
    cin>>ltRankOneTotal;
    cout<<"How many 1st Lieutenants  (O-2) / (1LT) are attending drill today?  "<<endl;
    cin>>ltRankTwoTotal;
    cout<<"How many Officers with paygrade (O-3) / Rank (CPT) are attending drill today?  "<<endl;
    cin>>captainsTotal;
    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;

    int totalEnlistedSoldiers = privatesRankOneTotal + privatesRankTwoTotal + privatesRankThreeTotal + specialistsCorporalsTotal + sergeantsTotal + staffSergeantsTotal + pltSergeantsTotal + masterSergeantsTotal;
    cout<<"Total enlisted soldiers at drill today:  "<<totalEnlistedSoldiers<<endl<<endl;

    int totalWarrantOfficers = chiefWarrantRankOneTotal + chiefWarrantRankTwoTotal + chiefWarrantRankThreeTotal;
    cout<<"Total Warrant Officers at drill today:  "<<totalWarrantOfficers<<endl<<endl;

    int totalOfficers = ltRankOneTotal + ltRankTwoTotal + captainsTotal;
    cout<<"Total Officers at drill today:  "<<totalOfficers<<endl<<endl;

    int totalSoldiers = totalEnlistedSoldiers + totalWarrantOfficers + totalOfficers;
    cout<<"Total soldiers (Enlisted, Warrant Officers, and Officers) at drill today:  "<<totalSoldiers<<endl;

    double privateOneTotalPay = privatesRankOneTotal*pvtOnePay;
    double privateTwoTotalPay = privatesRankTwoTotal*pvtTwoPay;
    double privateThreeTotalPay = privatesRankThreeTotal*pfcPay;
    double spcCplTotalPay = specialistsCorporalsTotal*SpcCplPay;
    double sgtTotalPay = sergeantsTotal*sgtPay;
    double ssgTotalPay = staffSergeantsTotal*ssgPay;
    double sfcTotalPay = pltSergeantsTotal*sfcPay;
    double msgTotalPay = masterSergeantsTotal*msgPay;

    double cwoOneTotalPay = chiefWarrantRankOneTotal*cwoOnePay;
    double cwoTwoTotalPay = chiefWarrantRankTwoTotal*cwoTwoPay;
    double cwoThreeTotalPay = chiefWarrantRankThreeTotal*cwoThreePay;

    double ltOneTotalPay = ltRankTwoTotal*ltTwoPay;
    double ltTwoTotalPay = ltRankOneTotal*ltOnePay;
    double cptTotalPay = captainsTotal*cptPay;

    double totalSoldiersDrillPay = privateOneTotalPay + privateTwoTotalPay + privateThreeTotalPay + spcCplTotalPay + sgtTotalPay + ssgTotalPay + sfcTotalPay + msgTotalPay + cwoOnePay + cwoTwoPay + cwoThreePay + ltOnePay + ltTwoPay + cptPay;
    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;

    double costOfLunch = 14.99;
    int soldiersProvidedLunch = 0;
    int loopCounter = 1;


    cout<<"How many soldiers were provided lunch today?"<<endl;
    cin>>soldiersProvidedLunch;
    cout<<endl;

    double totalLunchCost = soldiersProvidedLunch*costOfLunch;


    while (loopCounter == 1)
    {
        if (soldiersProvidedLunch <= totalSoldiers)
        {
            cout<<endl<<soldiersProvidedLunch<<" were provided lunch, the total cost of lunch today will be $"<<setiosflags(ios::fixed) << setprecision(2)<<totalLunchCost;
            loopCounter --;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<totalSoldiers<<" soldiers were at drill today, there cannot be more."<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<"Enter the number of soldiers that were provided lunch today."<<endl;
            cin>>soldiersProvidedLunch;
        }
    }

    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;


    double gasPrice = 3.87;
    double gallonsPumped = 0;

    cout<<"How many gallons of gasoline were purchased today:"<<endl;
    cin>>gallonsPumped;
    double finalGasPrice = gasPrice*gallonsPumped;

    cout<<endl;

    if (gallonsPumped >= 1)
    {
        cout<<endl<<"The total cost for gasoline today was $"<<setiosflags(ios::fixed) << setprecision(2) << finalGasPrice<<"."<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"No money spent on gasoline today.";
    }

    double dayDrillCost = finalGasPrice+totalLunchCost+totalSoldiersDrillPay;


    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<"Totals for today: "<<endl<<"**************************************"<<endl;
    cout<<"Total pay for soldiers present: $"<<setiosflags(ios::fixed) << setprecision(2)<<totalSoldiersDrillPay<<endl;
    cout<<"Total amount of money spent on lunch: $"<<setiosflags(ios::fixed) << setprecision(2)<<totalLunchCost<<endl;
    cout<<"Total amount of money spent on gas: $"<<setiosflags(ios::fixed) << setprecision(2)<<finalGasPrice<<endl<<"**************************************"<<endl;
    cout<<"Cost of drill today: $"<<setiosflags(ios::fixed) << setprecision(2)<<dayDrillCost<<endl;
    dayCounter --;
}
cout<<"Drill completed";
```

}

Comment: To make it more clear, the program should run, ask for the inputs, determine the totals for a day, and repeat twice and THEN output the total from the three days.

Comment: Where are you having problems? Would you know what to do for a single counter? And is it homework?

Comment: The problem isn't repeating it more than once, it's just getting totals from all three days to add up. And yes, it's for a project I'm working on.

Comment: Can't you just add the new entry to the previous one, thus having a running total?

Comment: Ha ha ha that's the issue, I have no idea how to do that. And I do want to clarify one thing - this wasn't a typical handout assignment that everyone got, this is my final project that I've made from scratch (the code and idea).

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand, but I put a simple loop that increments a counter in the answer below.

Comment: among other thing, the `while (loopCounter == 1)` stuff looks wrong, you can (and should) rearrange it, altogether with all the code; anyway, instead of scalar vars, you could use arrays, index is the day (0, 1, 2...), and, out of the day loop, for each array you sum its values and have a total... or, as said in another comment, keep a running sum for each var you want the grand total

Comment: When you find yourself writing substantially the same lines of code over and over to do substantially the same thing, it's time to take a step back and rethink the overall organization of your program. Your problem involves the notion of a type of person with a specific name and rate of pay where you need to ask how many are present for each day and compute the total amount paid -- but nowhere is that concept reflected in your program design. So you wind up cut/pasting that same logic *14* times. That's ridiculous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple loop that increments a single counter three times. From this, you can see hoe to generalize it for all your counters.

```
int someCounter = 0;

for (int day=0; day<3; ++day) { // loop three times

  // do your cin input here
  int tmp;
  cin >> tmp;
  someCounter += tmp; // increment running total

}

// print the total
```

If you have many counters, you may consider creating a `struct` or `class` holding these, defining `operator+=` for that class, and overriding `istream operator>>` for that class, but I get a feeling that may go beyond what is expected from your assignment. In any case, there are plenty of questions on SO explaining how to do that.

Comment: So in order to make this work I would have to put this at the start of the program I posted above?

Comment: @chrisvx930 your `while(dayCount > 0) { ... ; dayCount-- }` works the same if you initialize dayCount correctly, since all you do with that is nothing but decrementing it, i.e. just to count the repetition of the loop. Then, if you put the answer at the start, you obtain basically nothing: you've to adapt your code...

Comment: @chrisvx930 well, the code above gives you the logic to solve the problem. It isn't a matter of bolting that into your program. Rather, you should understand the logic and apply it.

Comment: I managed to successfully finish the code and it works great. Thank you for all your help, I appreciate it very much!